# Relaunching the app from background to foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

hi am developing an iPhone app. When i clicked a link in a UITextView, the link was opened in safari and my app went background. After closing the safari, i clicked my app icon and it was again brought to foreground. My question is that whether we can bring the app back to foreground automatically, without clicking the app icon, when i close safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't detect when the user closes Safari, what you could do is register a URL scheme for your application and make it a link in the web view. Basically a return to app button on the web page.
This tutorial should help you:http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: Here my problem is, here the link is clicked from the UITextView. The link was opened in safari. so what shall  do on clicking?

Comment: @krishh I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @krishh are you asking how to make it not open in safari?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle- i have a link in UITextView. i clicked the link and it is opened in safari. now what i want is, when i close this safari, i need to retain my application's last state

Comment: @krishh That's a completely different question.. just to clarify, are you asking how to make your app automatically reopen from Safari, or are you asking how to make your application retain its previous state when the user navigates back to your app on their own?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle-yes,i am asking how to retain its previous state when the user navigates back.

Comment: @krishh This should be done automatically... you're telling me it isn't?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle- when i click the back button from safari, its seems like my app is minimized, and on clicking the app icon, the app is launched retaining its last state. what i want is when i click the back button it should automatically relaunch the app without clicking the icon again

Comment: @krishh I just explained how to do that in my answer. There is NO WAY to make this happen automatically.

Comment: @krishh No problem, glad to help. If this post has helped you solve your problem be sure to mark it as correct my selecting the "check mark" next to it.